# Rotate camera in blender using python

Tags: python, camera, blender

I'm using Blender, I have a camera in position (x,y,z) pointing to (rx,ry,rz) and I need to rotate it around (0, 0, 0) (the radius is R) so that it still points to (rx,ry,rz). How can I implement it using python or is there a simple algorithm?

Comment: Do you absolutely require a script solution? Because what you've asked can be easily done without Python.

Comment: Also, this question might be more suitable for Blender.SE, imo. https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Highstaker I do, can you plz help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an actual algorithm, but may give you some hints.

Create an empty. Create a "Track To" constraint for your camera with the following parameters:

[image]

Set pivot point to "3D cursor":

[image]

Set 3D cursor where you want it. Since it is (0,0,0) in your case, you may simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it will be set there.

Now you can simply rotate your camera and it will circle around the 3D cursor while pointing at the target:

[image]

You can also do it from Python using [bpy.ops.transform.rotate](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=rotate#bpy.ops.transform.rotate) (bear in mind that this method takes *radians*, not degrees), **but** you need to do some mumbo-jumbo with contexts, or else it won't rotate around pivot. Basically, this has already been done for you in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6970/2324). The only thing I have to add is that if you have multiple viewports (3D Views, rather), it may not work at first, you just need to set pivot point to "3D cursor" in the others too, because the viewport Python grabs context from is kinda arbitrary. If you have only one, it shouldn't be a problem.